# inverse search from Okular to Kile

Tags: okular

Upgraded to 12:04
now can't get inverse search to work (from Okular to Kile)
My settings:
in Kile I have: Tools -> Mode -> Normal

in Okular I have: Settings-> Configure->Editor (and set Editor to Kile)

In Kile I have tried the buttons:  PDFLatex and then ForwardPDF
and also:  Latex and then ForwardPDF.

both bring up PDF in Okular, but SHIFT/leftClick does not do an inverse search.

A bug in Kile? in Okular? in 12.04? in me?

I'm using a System76 Pangolin P8. Thanks for any help

Comment: The following works:

Comment: Most of your comment was cut off and not posted. If you found a solution, please [post it as an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If you did not find a solution and are trying to provide more information, please *edit* your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check if you configuration is like the following:

http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-office/kile/quick_inverse.html

If yes, look at what happened to me: I had the same problem of inverse search not working.

The answer can't be simpler. **Be sure select Browse tool in Okular, not Zoom or anything else**.

That's it!

I lost 2 hours trying to find that solution.

Comment: Thanks! This prevented me from wasting a potential two hours trying to find the solution, especially at a time when I am writing something with a deadline in mind! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the "Modern" configuration for PDFLatex in Preferences -> Tools -> Build. This ensures the required synctex information is included in the PDF files, so Okular knows how to map locations in the PDF to locations in the source.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It seems this may be helpful ...but can you explain what this does, exactly, and why it solves this problem? (The best way to do so would be to edit your answer to expand it with the relevant information.)

Comment: I have no idea what it does, but it *did* solve my problem.