# Okular seems to have problems with inverse search for subdirectories (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, latex, okular

I am having trouble with the inverse search feature of okular. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

I compiled a document (MWE see below) and had issues. In fact I compile using the same settings in kile and get different behaviour depending on minor modifications in the tex code. However when looking at the synctex files these seem to be perfectly correct.

- If you compile with the titlepage and the theme Frankfurt, inverse serch is not working
- If compiling without title page all is ok
- If compiling without any explicit theme but with title page all is ok
- If compiling with theme Dresden (and title page) it is ok

MWE: You need two files to reproduce the error.

`main.tex:`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% \usetheme{Dresden}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\author{Me}
\title{Very important}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{src/foo.tex}

\end{document}
```

`src/foo.tex:`

```
\begin{frame}{Just a test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Itam A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Just click on any of the items to see the problem.

As far as I can see, the problem is inside okular as independent which editor is selected in the options of okular, the destination file is constructed wrong. All tested editor try to open the (absolute path of the) file `.`. If you have the `main.tex` in `/tmp/bar`, the editor will try to open `/tmp/bar` which is not possible as it is a directory of course.

Can anybody verify/reproduce this behaviour?

I am perfectly aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145567/inverse-search-from-okular-to-kile), however they seem not to be related. There not the file name is wrong but the GUI does not the expected things.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this problem seems to persist. However, I use an entirely different setup. My machine runs Windows 10. My editor is Emacs for Windows (GNU Emacs 28.2, build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) with AUCTeX (13.1.4). My TeX implementation is MiKTeX (23.5). The TeX engine is pdfTeX. My PDF-viewer is SumatraPDF (3.4.6 64 bit). Everything is up to date.

The problem, as far as I can tell, only occurs with the Frankfurt theme. I have tried a number of other themes. No other theme I've tried caused the problem.

If I do a forward search (C-c C-v) from Emacs, SumatraPDF says: "Unknown source file" followed by what looks like the correct path to the source file in question. If I do an inverse search (double clicking in SumatraPDF), the message is: "No synchronization info at this position."

Of course one can just use a different theme, but it's still strange that a beamer theme file can break forward/inverse search.